Search my own likes on X/twitter
This is not a dupe of How do I search within a Twitter user's likes?. I'm asking about searching my own likes, not that of other users. Answers to that older question claim that likes can be searched using TweetDeck (now pro.twitter.com), but that feature seems to be broken. If I click the search button after creating a column for my own likes, it searches my posts not my likes.
Ideally the answer should use pro.twitter.com, but an open source tool that doesn't require paying >=$100/mo for the X API would also be acceptable. I'm not sure if the free API allows fetching likes. The tool may have to search an archive from https://x.com/settings/download_your_data.
